# Issue in playing append stream video using ffplay

Tags: video, ffmpeg, stream, udp

I have played the received video using ffplay as follows,

```
ffplay scr.avi
```

***Note:
The scr.avi file is still expanded based on received stream in remote host system as follows***

```
ffmpeg -i udp://192.168.0.54:1234 -c copy "scr.avi"
```

Once I have run ffplay , it can able to play only the duration when it was run. But I need to play expanded video stream also.

Anyone can help me to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Why not do `ffplay udp://192.168.0.54:1234`?

Comment: I have also tried   **$ffplay udp://192.168.0.54:1234** But It can not play like a continuous video(i.e, second by second). It can not update the screen continuously.

Comment: Sender side command as I have used **$ ffmpeg -f x11grab -s 1600x900 -r 30 -i :0.0 -qscale 0.1 -vcodec huffyuv -f segment -segment_time 60 -reset_timestamps 1 "scrCap%03d.avi" -f mpegts udp://192.168.0.55:1234**